# Loading an image as Texture2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, texture2d

In my program, I want to save some screenshots and load them later on to compute somethings. I created a methode to compute the image names:

```
static public string generatePhotoName (string cameraName, float time)
{
    return "G:/Data/unity/cameraDemo/" + 
        DataController.measurmentPath + 
        "/photos" + "/" + 
        cameraName + "/" + 
        time.ToString () + "_" + cameraName + ".png";
}
```

This worked fine for saving, but when I try to load an image, `File.Exists (filePath)`returns `false`.

But when I hardcoded the filepath, loading works fine too:

```
static public string generatePhotoName (string cameraName, float time)
{
    return "G:/Data/unity/cameraDemo/demo/photos/Camera/test.png";
}
```

It even works with "real" image names(i.e. 3.827817_Camera.png).

Using `Path.Combine(...)` and changing "/" to "\" did not change anything...

// edit: this is my load methode

```
static public Texture2D loadPhotoToTexture (string filePath)
{

    Texture2D tex = null;
    byte[] fileData;

    if (File.Exists (filePath)) {
        fileData = File.ReadAllBytes (filePath);
        tex = new Texture2D (2, 2);
        tex.LoadImage (fileData); //..this will auto-resize the texture dimensions.
    } else {
        Debug.Log (filePath + " does not exist");
    }
    return tex;
}`
```

// edit2: some more code

This is how I call the methode 
`Texture2D photo = DataController.loadPhotoToTexture(photoData.getFileName ());`

And this is my class `PhotoData`

```
public class PhotoData : BaseData
{
    private string _cameraName;

    public string cameraName {
    get { return _cameraName; }
    set { _cameraName = value; }
    }

    private float _time;

    public float time {
        get { return _time; }
        set { _time = value; }
    }

    public PhotoData ()
    {
    }

    public PhotoData (string cameraName, float time)
    {
        _cameraName = cameraName;
        _time = time;
    }

    public string getFileName ()
    {
        return PlayerController.generatePhotoName (_cameraName, _time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you loading the file ? Also paths should have @"\" or "\\" not "/".

Comment: In the end I will get a batch of images as files and I have to load them in my program. As written, I changed slashs to backslashs, but it did not help. The second version of `generatePhotoName`does work even with "/"!

Comment: Can you show us a string returned by the first version of the method?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis `G:/Data/unity/cameraDemo/demo/photos/Camera/2.46422_Camera.png`

Comment: Can you post everything related to your question. Including the loading.

Comment: @deathismyfriend just added the methode

Comment: Also show us where you calculate filePath.

Comment: What happens if you don't take the `time` parameter into account when assembling the filename? (I'm suspecting that you are recalculating the time and the floating point issues are ruining your filename.)

Comment: @deathismyfriend do you talk about `DataController.measurmentPath`?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis It does not change anything... I save the time once in a `float time` and use this variable for future calls

Comment: No in the method loadPhotoToTexture(string filePath) where do you get filePath from ?

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with the posted code. Can you show us the code that calls this method?

Comment: I edited the question to add some more code

Comment: This is very strange. Can you tell us what happens in these two (separate) cases: (a) if you change `float` to `decimal` and (b) if you store the string instead of the camera name and time?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis (b) does not change anything. At which point should I change `float`to `decimal` for (a)? I don't think it's a problem with the float, since "test.png" does not work either...

Comment: Yeah, you are right about (a). But the fact that (b) doesn't work is quite surprising. Can you reproduce this problem in a small new project? (And if yes, can you post it so that we can try it as well?)

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I got a new idea, why this does not work. in one `Update()` I first take the screen shot and then I almost immeditaly try to load the photo. Maybe saving the photo needs some more time. I gonna check this an let you know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that I tried to save and load the screenshots in one `Update()`-call.

I fixed it by changing it to right-click to take and save a screenshot and left-click to load the screenshot.

Comment: If you've fixed the problem, you can accept your own answer, so that the question doesn't appear in the listings as unanswered (which is generally taken to mean "still looking for an answer").

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store images to a certain file on disk, not inside your game folder structure, do this: create a folder, and store its location (filepath). For example:

```
string screenshotFileName = time.ToString () + "_" + cameraName + ".png"
string screenshotDirectory;
screenshotDirectory = @"C:\someFolder\anotherFolder\";
try { Directory.CreateDirectory(directory); }
catch (Exception e)
{ //you should catch each exception separately
   if (e is DirectoryNotFoundException || e is UnauthorizedAccessException)
       Debug.LogError("OMG PANIC");
}
FileInfo filepath = new FileInfo(screenshotDirectory+screenshotFileName);
if(filepath.Exists)
{
    //load the file
}
```

You could also simply create a folder, with a relative path, which will be in the same folder as your executable, by changing the screenshotDirectory to
     `screenshotDirectory = @"screenshots\"+cameraName+@"\";`

Edit:
You seem to load the texture correctly. Are you assigning it to the material's main texture? Where is your code encountering the problem? For example if you're running this script on the same object that you want the texture to be applied:

```
this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = loadedTexture;
```

Also, when you want to load images, it's best that you use the Resources folder, which uses forwards slashes, not . Store everything that you might want to load on runtime there, and use Resources.Load().

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks so far. I have seen this @"\" before and read, that it is similar to "\\" but I don't know what it is called. Can you tell me, so i can look it up?

Comment: It's called a verbatim string literal. It means take this string EXACTLY as it is (verbatim), don't try to interpret characters like \n \t etc.

Comment: I don't want to apply the texture to any object. I just need to read some pixels in every screenshot. Whenever I click, the program should take a screenshot and save the clicked point in world coordinates. Later I want to find a matching pixel in the screenshots and dye the saved point in the correct color.